# Depths in clay content map

Tags: soilgrids

I noticed that, in contrast to the organic carbon content which is provided different soil layers, i.e. 0-15 cm, 15-30 cm, etc., the clay content is provided for specific discreet depths, namely 5 cm, 15 cm, 30 cm, etc.

Are these the values in that specific depths or is 5 cm representative for the 0-5 cm layer and so on?

Ultimately, my question is, what should someone do to obtain the average clay percentage for 2 m depth, meaning from 0 to 2 m?

Comment: Don't you think this question is better suited for EarthScience.SE? If not, please make clear why you think this is on point at GIS.SE.

Comment: @Erik It's a question about a GIS-based soil data resource, so it's at least tangentially related to GIS. There's already a good answer so I would lean towards keeping it open.

Comment: @csk sure, there is a small relation, but in the past similar questions have been closed regularly. So, especially since data-request are also considered offtopic, I think clarification by the OP is required.

Comment: There are other questions about SoilGrids in this web site. Why was this question closed?

Answer (score 1):

In the 2017 release predictions were made for specific depths, at the edges of the intervals specified by the GlobalSoilMap project. To obtain an average you can apply the trapezoidal rule described in [this article](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0169748).

For the 2019 preview, predictions were made for the intervals themselves. You can assume the value is constant within the interval and perform an average weighted by depth thickness.